# To make the draggable point appear on top of other layers - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox

I have a draggable pin and want it to appear on top of other layers. Here is the code used for creating the pin and it always appears below other layers and even the drag action happens below the layers.

```
val centerScreen = mapBox.projection.toScreenLocation(mapBox.cameraPosition.target)
newLatLng = mapBox.projection.fromScreenLocation(centerScreen)

val pin = SymbolOptions()
    .withLatLng(LatLng(newLatLng.latitude, newLatLng.longitude))
    .withIconImage("create-pin")
    .withIconSize(1.0f)
    .withDraggable(true)
    .withSymbolSortKey(1.0F)

symbolManager.apply {
    iconAllowOverlap = true
    textAllowOverlap = true
    iconKeepUpright = true
    create(pin)
}
```

The pin has to appear on top of other layers.
Please help